# Detecting whether a join is possible or not

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, database

I am building a system which detects when tables can be joined together. For example, in the case of two simple tables - If `Table A` has a primary key which links to a foreign key in `Table B`, then the system would detect that a join is possible between the two tables. This has worked perfectly so far in C#, by simply iterating through all foreign keys and checking to see which tables have a primary key which references the respective FK.

However, things have become complex now. I have added the notion of a virtual table, in the form of a `View`. Thus, joined tables can be used to create a view, and the same view can then be used to join with other tables. This is done so as to be able to simplify cases where there might be joins over 3 or more tables. Thus allowing the user to join 3 or more tables together in a simple manner, thanks to the use of views.

My problem is that views do not seem to store concepts such as primary and foreign keys. Thus, how would I go about detecting whether a join is possible or not between a specific table and a view? For example, I could have the following view:

```
CREATE VIEW [View A] 
AS 
SELECT  Children.Child_ID,
        Social_Workers.Social_ID 
FROM Children 
INNER JOIN Social_Workers 
    ON Children.Social_ID = Social_Workers.Social_ID
```

Next, I could decide to join that view with a table like so:

```
SELECT  [View A].Child_ID,
        Sponsors.User_ID 
FROM [View A]
INNER JOIN Sponsors 
    ON [View A].Child_ID = Sponsors.Child_ID
```

How would I go about detecting the possibility of a join between the view and table?

Comment: "Possible" is a bit misleading - it is always possible to join two tables on any columns they have.

Comment: @Argeman - What I mean by possible is - if a relationship is detected between the two tables :)

Comment: I agree with @Argeman and more, beware that there are a slew of systems in use *(EAV anyone?)* that get's joined but doesn't have foreign keys. As per your question, I doubt there's little else to do than to get the VIEW's definition and parse that. Essentially, that's also what the optimizer does, replace the view with the actual underlying SQL statement. Perhaps if you told us your use case, we can give you other alternatives.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers - I'm basically creating a query buider which is to handle complex joins. Users can in theory create an inner join between two tables for example, and join the result with another table. This whole result can then in theory be joined with another result, in turn containing many tables. This is the main context of the problem, hence why I have chosen to use views. Each result of a join is turned into a view, to make the generated SQL statements much more managable. The part i'm trying to work on at this stage is joining a table to a view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two approaches, and which you choose depends on whether you want fast solution which makes changes to DBMS, or do the hard work.

---

**Get schema of your view, create a temporary table in DBMS and use your existing logic**

Even though you'd have to create table to match views schema, I consider this a quick solution as all burden of testing is transferred to SQL Server.

---

**Load schemas of both tables to a DataTable and do tests manually**

- Check that number of join columns are both for parent and child table
- Check that types of matching columns exactly match in both tables
- Check that each column appears only once in their side of join
- Check that there is not already a relation in DB with exact same columns
- Check that child columns do not have unique (and depending on your need not-null) constraint

Comment: Is the second approach carried out to replace the DBMS's inbuilt relationship checks? Since all columns are essentially equal in a view?

Comment: Yes, second approach is suggested to replace DBMS's checks. I don't understand second part of your question. Checks I mentioned are general checks for identity join. I assumed that you want to ignore that your "virtual tables" are actually views, and that at some point you will want to retrieve data from the view to a .NET DataTable and create a DataRelation between it and another table.